# Producer consumer collection with ability to read and write batches of data

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer, tpl-dataflow

I'm looking for a collection like [BufferBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414(v=vs.110).aspx)

but with methods like:

```
SendAsync<T>(T[])
T[] ReceiveAsync<T>()
```

Is anyone can help with?

Comment: Did you check the extension methods?

Comment: @Hackerman, yep... doublechecked ;) can you point me if I'm missing something?

Comment: Why don't you use BufferBlock? BTW it does have such methods. Check [How to: Implement a Producer-Consumer Dataflow Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern)

Comment: As for something *other* than Bufferblock that supports pub/sub explicitly, you can try the new System.Threading.Tasks.Channels package

Comment: [ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.receiveasync?view=netcore-2.1) and [SendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.sendasync?view=netcore-2.1) are available as extension methods. Perhaps you need to cast the BufferBlock to the appropriate interface first?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `ReceiveAsync` and `SendAsync` do not handle arrays.

Comment: @JSteward, yes exactly: the question about collection able to send and receive batches

Comment: Added another option, the `BatchBlock` might work better for you but it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods aren't available, `SendAsync<T>` only takes a single `T` and `RecieveAsync<T>` only returns a single `T`, not arrays.

```
SendAsync<T>(T[])
T[] ReceiveAsync<T>()
```

However there is [`TryReceiveAll<T>(out IList<T> items)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194755(v=vs.110).aspx) and you can call `SendAsync<T>` in a loop to send an array into the `BufferBlock` or write your own extension method, something like this:

```
public static async Task SendAllAsync<T>(this ITargetBlock<T> block, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
         await block.SendAsync(item)
    }
}
```

Note that `SendAsync` does return a bool indicating acceptance of the messages, you could return an array of booleans or just return if any of them come back false but that's up to you.

Likely it would be easier to use a `BatchBlock<T>` that you can send items to as singles using a loop but emits the items in batches, which would be easier than using `TryRecieveAll` if you're building a pipeline. [BatchBlock Walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-using-batchblock-and-batchedjoinblock-to-improve-efficiency) and [BatchBlock Example](http://www.riptutorial.com/csharp/example/10606/batchblock-t-)

Comment: Thanks for the BatchBlock, it's close to what I was looking for. Ideally if collection can handle batch input asynchronously and can a read asynchronously a batch with just a max size without outside timer

Answer (score 0):

[ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.receiveasync?view=netcore-2.1) and [SendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.sendasync?view=netcore-2.1) are available as extension methods on the ISourceBlock and ITargetBlockT<> interfaces. This means that you have to cast the block to those interfaces in order to use the extension methods, eg :

```
var buffer=new BufferBlock<string>();

var source=(ISourceBlock<string>)buffer;
var target=(ITargetBlock<string>)buffer;

await target.SendAsync("something");
```

Typically that's *not* a problem because all Dataflow methods accept interfaces, not concrete types, eg :

```
async Task MyProducer(ITargetBlock<string> target)
{
    ...
    await target.SendAsync(..);
    ...
    target.Complete();
}

async Task MyConsumer(ISourceBlock<string> target)
{
    ...
    var message=await target.ReceiveAsync();
    ...
}

public static async Task Main()
{
    var buffer=new BufferBlock<string>();
    MyProducer(buffer);
    await MyConsumer(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attention and effort. But my question about reading and writing batches of elements. I know about single element send/receive this methods described in article by link in my question.

Comment: @gabba Then you should use BatchBlock, not BufferBlock

Comment: thanks. Will use BatchBlock with BufferBlock as JSteward advised